# MySQL: select list of battles, not shared between 2 users

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select list of "battle_id", which first "user_id" have, but not shared with second "user_id",

battles (table structure):

```
id     user_id     battle_id
0         1           44
1         1           55
2         1           66
3         2           44
4         2           77
5         3           88
6         3           99
7         4           44
8         4           55
9         4           66
```

sample of input and output:

```
example 1: input [user_id = 1, user_id = 2] output => 55,66
example 2: input [user_id = 1, user_id = 3] output => 44,55,66
example 3: input [user_id = 1, user_id = 4] output => null
```

thanks,

Comment: I tested multiple queries but not working as expected

Comment: Search the Web for `FULL OUTER JOIN` - This will get all battles involving either User1 or User2.  Then, using a `WHERE` clause, you can filter out the battles involving both users.  (Or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for battles User1 has that User2 does not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `user_id` int, `battle_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `user_id`, `battle_id`)
VALUES
    (0, 1, 44),
    (1, 1, 55),
    (2, 1, 66),
    (3, 2, 44),
    (4, 2, 77),
    (5, 3, 88),
    (6, 3, 99),
    (7, 4, 44),
    (8, 4, 55),
    (9, 4, 66)
;
```

**Query:**

```
select
battle_id
from
t
group by battle_id
having sum(user_id = 1) >= 1 and sum(user_id = 2) = 0
```

**Result:**

```
| battle_id |
|-----------|
|        55 |
|        66 |
```

**Explanation:**

You don't need to self join like suggested in comments. Do it in one go.
The `user_id = 'whatever'` inside the `sum()` function in `having` clause returns either `true` or `false`, meaning `1` or `0`.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8099/1/0).

Comment: When suggesting this method PLEASE give the Op fair warning that it will always yield a Full Table Scan.  On tiny tables this is fine.  On large user bases this would be the worst possible performer.  EXISTS and OUTER JOIN variants will make use of index scans and seeks, with dramatically lower reads and cpu cycles.

Comment: That is simply untrue: HAVING statements do not utilise indexes at all.  This query WILL use a full table scan, the alternatives can use indexes to avoid that, this Does Not.

Comment: Evidence that then.  Show the Op a plan from a real RDBMS where applying a predicate to an aggregate can short circuit that to a predicate on the underlying table and so apply it to an index.  It doesn't happen.  Your SUM() statements apply to all rows, post aggregation, and Then the predicate is applied.

Comment: Your plan evidences an index can be used by the GROUP BY but Does Not get used by the HAVING clause.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2938b/4 - Please look at the explain plans and take specific note of the Rows column.  Your query is unable to pre-filter the table, it causes a full table scan.  The second and third queries only operate on a subset of the rows, an index range scan.  You have spotted that the query uses an index in your case, but this is Solely for the purposes of ordering the data to be friendly for grouping, but Not for filtering.

Comment: Okay, okay, you're right. Cleaning up now, upvoting your comment. Post your answer and I'll upvote and suggest that OP accepts yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries here. Somthing like that:-

```
SELECT battle_id
FROM battles
WHERE user_id IN ('Your first user_id', 'Your second user_id')
AND battle_id NOT IN (SELECT battle_id
                      FROM battles
                      WHERE user_id = 'Your second user_id');
```